# Array with 4 elements: need to compare max+min and the other 2 elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with 4 values in it, called array `r`, using the numpy array command.

```
from numpy import array, amax, amin
r = array([r1,r2,r3,r4]
```

I need to sum the max and the min of this array:

```
g_1 = amax(r)+amin(r)
```

Now I need to compare this value (`g_1`) with the sum of the two other elements of the array (I don't know what value is the max when I program this part of the code) and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: How do you want to "compare" them?

Comment: I will need to see if a condition like "a>=b" is respected and then use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from numpy import sum
g_2 = sum(r) - g_1
comp = g_1 <= g_2
```

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the other two elements of the array is simply the sum of all elements of the array, minus the max and min values: `sum(r) - g_1`

Answer (score 0):

You might as well sort the array, will probably require less compares overall:

```
r_sort = np.sort(r)
g_1 = r_sort[0] + r_sort[-1]
g_2 = r_sort[1] + r_sort[2]
```

Comment: I think that there is an error in your code.
It should be:
    g_1 = r_sort[0] + r_sort[3]
and not:
    g_1 = r_sort[0] + r_sort[-1].
Am I wrong?

Comment: Using negative index means counting from the end, so `r_sort[-1]` is equal to `r_sort[3]` when `len(r_sort) == 4`

Comment: @Hamatti has explained it very well. The way I wrote it, `g_1` will always be the max plus the min, if you hardcode the max index as you propose it will only work properly for 4 item arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use a *for* and *if* to see if I can do it right and the code I wrote seems to work:

```
from numpy import array, amax, amin
r=array([r1,r2,r3,r4])
g_1=amax(r)+amin(r)
for j in range (size(r)):
    if r[j] != amax(r) and r[j] != amin(r):
         g_2+=r[j]
```

This code seems to return correctly the g_2 I was looking for. Not the best solution, what do you think about it?